# Reportviewer tool missing in visual studio 2017 RC

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2017

I just started to write reporting software in new version of visual studio named visual studio 2017 RC but just noticed that core reportviewing tools is missing from both windows forms and WPF application template. Can anyone tell me why the reportviewer tool is disappeared from visual studio 2017 ? Really having trouble without it . Is there any alternate to work with this tool in new visual studio ?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

** Update**: 11/19/2019

Microsoft has released a new version of the control `150.1400.0` in their Nuget library. My short testing shows that it works again in the forms designer where `150.1357.0` and `150.1358.0` did not. This includes being able to resize and modify the ReportViewer Tasks on the control itself.

** Update**: 8/18/2019

Removing the latest version and rolling back to `150.900.148.0` seems to work on multiple computers I'm using with VS2017 and VS2019.

You can roll back to 150.900.148 in the Nuget solution package manager. It works similarly to the previous versions. Use the drop down box to select the older version.

[image]

It may be easier to manually delete references to post 150.900 versions of ReportViewer and readd them than it is to fix them.

Remember to restart Visual Studio after changing the toolbox entry.

**Update**: 8/7/2019

A newer version of the ReportViewer control has been released, probably coinciding with Visual Studio 2019. I was working with V150.1358.0.

Following the directions in this answer gets the control in the designer's toolbox. But once dropped on the form it doesn't display. The control shows up below the form as a non-visual component.

This is working as designed according to *Microsoft SQL BI* support. This is the group responsible for the control.

While you still cannot interact with the control directly, these additional steps give a workaround so the control can be sized on the form. While now visible, the designer treats the control as if it didn't exist.

I've created a feedback request at the suggestion of Microsoft SQL BI support.  Please consider voting on it to get Microsoft's attention.

[Microsoft Azure Feedback page - Restore Designtime features of the WinForms ReportViewer Control](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/38324749-restore-the-visual-studio-designer-functionality-o)

Additional steps:

- After adding the reportviewer to the WinForm
- Add a Panel Control to the WinForm.
- In the form's form.designer.cs file, add the Reportviewer control to the panel.

  ```
    // 
    // panel1
    // 
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.reportViewer1);
  ```
- Return to the form's designer, you should see the reportViewer on the panel
- In the Properties panel select the ReportViewer in the controls list dropdown
- Set the reportViewer's Dock property to Fill

Now you can position the reportViewer by actually interacting with the panel.

**Update**: Microsoft released a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started) on April 18, 2017 describing how to configure and use the reporting tool in Visual Studio 2017.

Visual Studio 2017 does not have the `ReportViewer` tool installed by default in the ToolBox. Installing the extension **Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio** and then adding that to the ToolBox results in a non-visual component that appears below the form.

Microsoft Support had told me this is a bug, but as of April 21, 2017 it is "working as designed".

The following steps need to be followed for each project that requires `ReportViewer`.

- If you have `ReportViewer` in the Toolbox, remove it.  Highlight, right-click and delete.

  - You will have to have a project with a form open to do this.

Edited 8/7/2019 - It looks like the current version of the RDLC Report Designer extension no longer interferes. You need this to actually edit the reports.

- <s>If you have the **Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio** extension installed, uninstall it.</s>
- Close your solution and restart Visual Studio. This is
  a crucial step, errors will occur if VS is not restarted when
  switching between solutions.
- Open your solution.
- Open the NuGet Package Manager Console (`Tools/NuGet Package Manager/Package Manager Console`)
- At the PM> prompt enter this command, case matters.

  `Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms`

  You should see text describing the installation of the package.

Now we can temporarily add the `ReportViewer` tool to the tool box.

- Right-click in the toolbox and use `Choose Items...`
- We need to browse to the proper DLL that is located in the solutions `Packages` folder, so hit the browse button.
- In our example we can paste in the packages folder as shown in the text of Package Manager Console.

  `C:\Users\jdoe\Documents\Projects\_Test\ReportViewerTest\WindowsFormsApp1\packages`
- Then double click on the folder named
  `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.140.340.80`

  The version number will probably change in the future.
- Then double-click on `lib` and again on `net40`.
- Finally, double click on the file `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll`

  You should see `ReportViewer` checked in the dialog.  Scroll to the right and you will see the version 14.0.0.0 associated to it.
- Click OK.

`ReportViewer` is now located in the ToolBox.

- Drag the tool to the desired form(s).
- Once completed, delete the `ReportViewer` tool from the tool box. You can't use it with another project.
- You may save the project and are good to go.

Remember to restart Visual Studio any time you need to open a project with `ReportViewer` so that the DLL is loaded from the correct location. If you try and open a solution with a form with `ReportViewer` without restarting you will see errors indicating that the “`The variable 'reportViewer1' is either undeclared or was never assigned.`“.

If you add a new project to the same solution you need to create the project, save the solution, restart Visual Studio and then you should be able to add the `ReportViewer` to the form.  I have seen it not work the first time and show up as a non-visual component.

When that happens, removing the component from the form, deleting the `Microsoft.ReportViewer.*` references from the project, saving and restarting usually works.

Comment: @Rich Shealer is it same process for MVC Project?

Comment: @KinjalPatel I do not work with MVC, so I can't give you a quality answer.

Comment: One additional thing that affected me: I had to switch from targeting `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile` to `.NET Framework 4`.

Comment: Does it makes some trouble from previous version or same with previous ? Because i have made my project in Vs2015 Enterprise and in there i have RDLC Report built in ?

Comment: This is webforms, !

Comment: this works. but "restart Visual Studio any time you need to open a project with ReportViewer" is really [unacceptable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07So_lJQyqw).

Comment: I can confirm that these steps doesnt work with Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms 150.1358.0.

What worked for me was to downgrade the extension to 140.1000.523

Comment: @IlyasFoo - Thanks for the confirmation. Please see my update at the top of this answer. There is a feedback link to Microsoft that can be voted to get Microsoft to fix it.

Answer (score 16):

Update: this answer works with both ,Visual Sudio 2017 and 2019

For me it worked by the following three steps:

1. Updating Visual Studio to the latest build.
2. Adding ***Report / Report Wizard*** to the ***Add/New Item*** menu by:

   - Going to Visual Studio menu ***Tools/Extensions and Updates***
   - Choose ***Online*** from the left panel.
   - Search for ***Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio***
   - Download and install it.
3. Adding Report viewer control by:

   - Going to ***NuGet Package Manager***.
   - Installing ***Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms***
   - Go to the folder that contains Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll: ***%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.reportingservices.reportviewercontrol.winforms\140.1000.523\lib\net40***
   - Drag the ***Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll*** file and drop it at Visual Studio ***Toolbox*** Window.

For ***WebForms*** applications:

1. The same.
2. The same.
3. Adding Report viewer control by:

   - Going to ***NuGet Package Manager***.
   - Installing ***Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms***
   - Go to the folder that contains Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll file: ***%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.reportingservices.reportviewercontrol.webforms\140.1000.523\lib\net40***
   - Drag the ***Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll*** file and drop it at Visual Studio ***Toolbox*** Window.

That's all!

Answer (score 3):

Please NOTE that this procedure of adding the reporting services described by @Rich Shealer above will be iterated every time you start a different project. In order to avoid that:

1. If you may need to set up a different computer (eg, at home without internet), then keep your downloaded installers from the marketplace somewhere safe, ie:

   - Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices.vsix, and
   - Microsoft.RdlcDesigner.vsix
2. Fetch the following libraries from the packages or bin folder of the application you have created with reporting services in it:

   - Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
   - Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll
   - Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design.dll
   - Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
   - Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
3. Install the 2 components from 1 above
4. Add the dlls from 2 above as references (Project>References>Add...)
5. (Optional) Add Reporting tab to the toolbar
6. Add Items to Reporting tab
7. Browse to the bin folder or where you have the above dlls and add them

You are now good to go! ReportViewer icon will be added to your toolbar, and you will also now find Report and ReportWizard templates added to your Common list of templates when you want to add a New Item... (Report) to your project

NB: When set up using Nuget package manager, the Report and ReportWizard templates are grouped under Reporting. Using my method described above however does not add the Reporting grouping in installed templates, but I dont think it is any trouble given that it enables you to quickly integrate rdlc without internet and without downloading what you already have from Nuget every time!

Comment: Hi @Hannington Mambo, thanks for your useful solution.I have done your steps and now i can see reportviewer control in my toolbox and i can add it to my form, but i do not have  Report and Report  Wizard items in my Add New Item panel. Can you please help me...

Comment: Glad to have helped! I was able to get them in my Add New Item... installed templates. I explained that the Report template group will not be available. Sometimes you may need to close vs, remove and add the dlls

Answer (score 2):

Download Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio
from this link.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001

Microsoft explain the steps in details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017

The following steps summarizes the above article.

**Adding the Report Viewer control to a new web project:**

1. Create a new ASP.NET Empty Web Site or open an existing ASP.NET project.
2. Install the Report Viewer control NuGet package via the NuGet package manager console.
   From Visual Studio -> Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

   ```
   Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms
   ```
3. Add a new .aspx page to the project and register the Report Viewer control assembly for use within the page.

   ```
   <%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
   ```
4. Add a ScriptManagerControl to the page.
5. Add the Report Viewer control to the page. The snippet below can be updated to reference a report hosted on a remote report server.

   ```
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote">
    <ServerReport ReportPath="" ReportServerUrl="" /></rsweb:ReportViewer>
   ```

The final page should look like the following.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sample" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>        
       <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote">
           <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="https://AContosoDepartment/ReportServer" ReportPath="/LatestSales" />
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Best instructions I have found on the subject. Everything worked as described until the final step: 
"ReportViewer is now located in the ToolBox." It is not there. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is Microsoft going away from SSRS?

Comment: @Nate Do you mean Microsoft will not support SSRS in the future? if you mean this, the article above from Microsoft. So Microsoft supports SSRS till now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're like me and tried a few of these methods and are stuck at the point that you have the control in the toolbox and can draw it on the form but it disappears from the form and puts it down in the components, then simply edit the designer and add the following in the appropriate area of InitializeComponent() to make it visible:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.reportViewer1);

or

[ContainerControl].Controls.Add(this.reportViewer1);
```

You'll also need to make adjustments to the location and size manually after you've added the control.

Not a great answer for sure, but if you're stuck and just need to get work done for now until you have more time to figure it out, it should help.

Comment: I ended up downgrading my version via nuget package manager to the following and it started behaving normally: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms version 140.1000.523