# Reporting Template (RDLC) not exists in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Reporting template Component (RDLC) not exists to as New Item in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

How to resolve this?

I have tried by installing SQL Server Data Tools.

Previously it works for me in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Have you checked https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a bug in the extension **Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio** that the `ReportViewer` shows up as a non-visual component.

Instead use the NuGet Package *Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms* for each project that will use the ReportViewer.  Part of the solution involves removing the `ReportViewer` from the toolbox after use and restarting Visual Studio before opening the next project/solution.

Please see this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43375646/439320) to a similar question for step by step details.

Answer (score 8):

The RDLC editor for VS2017 is only available as a VSIX installer from the marketplace: [Download](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001)

Comment: This link seems to return 404 not found (accessed 06/20/2018).

Comment: the link worked for me, but the installer terminated with a log message that it is only for community edition (!?) and "VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products". I have VS Enterprise 2017 from MSDN volume licensing.

Comment: try this   : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001

Answer (score -1):

I have just used VS2015 to add the new item. All other stuff seems to be fine in VS2017 (bearing in mind that you installed the VSIX extension)