# Rdlc editor does not exist in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer

I need use SSRS to generate reports in Visual Studio 2017.
Firstly I installed report viewer control via nuget: Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms

After installed the control, I got the report viewer in the toolbox. But the RDLC editor is not in the new project dialog.

So I downloaded and installed [Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqlReportingServices.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001#overview)

After doing this, I found the report viewer disappeared from the toolbox and RDLC editor is still not in the new project dialog window.

Did I missing some other stuffs to install? Or I did something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answer to this question: [Reporting Template (RDLC) not exits in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848451/reporting-template-rdlc-not-exits-in-visual-studio-2017)

"There is a bug in the extension Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio that the ReportViewer shows up as a non-visual component."