# Report Viewer doesn't appear in Toolbox - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, reportviewer

After following the steps that it's defines in here [Reportviewer tool missing in visual studio 2017 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713705/reportviewer-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2017-rc/43375646#43375646). 
I can't still make it work the Report Viewer, this is how it appears in the Toolbox:

[image]

This ReportViewer tool only appear after right-click on the Toolbox and then i selected on 'Show All'. After doing all of this i still can not drag it to the design report.

I do not know how to solve this.

Comment: Hi have you installed the report viewer in nugget

Comment: Yes, i installed from nugget. I followed all the steps that it's described in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713705/reportviewer-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2017-rc/43375646#43375646

Comment: What version of windows do you use? That problem gave me windows7 but in Windows 10 it didn't give me problems anymore.-

Comment: Avoid answering questions with questions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23718668)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the answer [Reportviewer tool missing in visual studio 2017 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713705/reportviewer-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2017-rc/43375646#43375646), this can be done by:

- Delete any report viewer in the Toolbox
- Open the Reportviewer package folder in your project (D:...packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.140.340.80\lib\net40)
- Drag the file "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll" (or Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll) into the Toolbox of Visual Studio.

[Check the GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gji8k.gif)

Comment: In my case, for a Webforms ASP.NET app, I fixed it by right click in Toolbox > Choose Items. Then choosing Browse in ".NET Framework Components" tab. Then selecting `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll` from the project's `\bin` folder.