# ReportViewer control are not enabled in the active designer. - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to use the RDLC Report Viewer on a MVC application but I can't use it.

I installed the extension Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio, after doing that I also installed this package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms from the Nuget Package Manager Console.

Then I tried to choose that package for adding to the Toolbox and I get this message:

[image]

After pressing the OK button the ReportViewer is still not visible in the Toolbox. I followed these instructions too but still doesn't work [Reportviewer tool missing in visual studio 2017 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713705/reportviewer-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2017-rc/43375646#43375646)

Answer (score 1):

For **Visual Studio 2019** -->

01 : Go to **Extensions** Menu

02 : **Manage extensions** --> Search **"Microsoft RDLC Report Designer"**

03 : Download and install **"Microsoft RDLC Report Designer"**

- Create asp.net **Empty web project**
- add **Report.aspx** and **Report.rdlc** files to the project.

04: Go to **Reference** folder --> **Manage nuget packages**

05: Search **Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms** and Install

So far there is not tab called "**Microsoft Sql Server**" under toolbox. we should do this way for open it.

04: Open **Report.rdlc** file

05: After that open **Report.aspx** file

06: Now you can see there is a tab called as **Microsoft Sql Server** under toolbox

07: you can find **Reportviewer** inside **Microsoft Sql Server** tab

08: Drag **ReportViewer** control to **Report.aspx**

Comment: For those who have problems with this issue, I suggest you create an empty project from scratch and follow the above steps.