# ReportViewer Missing tools in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. The following controls were sucessfully added but not enabled in the active designer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, reporting, rdlc

I am Using VS2017 enterprise.I am trying to show rdlc report in report viewer but i can not able to find any ReportViewer in Toolbox.I have tried all solutions step by step which is related with this problem but still now not getting any result.when I choose **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll** and press ok then it says **The following controls were sucessfully added but not enabled in the active designer.**

I just add some images related to this problem.

[image: when I Add the dll then it says this]

[image: after press ok then the Reportviewer shows me like this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713705/reportviewer-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2017-rc

Comment: I tried this but not working.. @AnkitVijay