# How to display rdlc report in Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, rdlc, winapp

I am trying to add a `.rdlc` report to a C# Windows application using Visual Studio 2017 Community, but the `ReportViewer` control shows as a non-visual component below the form.

I have tried the solution I found here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/install-rdlc-extensions-in-visual-studio-2017/

and here: [Reportviewer tool missing in visual studio 2017 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713705/reportviewer-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2017-rc/43375646#43375646)

I want to be able to display the `.rdlc` report on the form, just like the way it appears on other versions of Visual Studio. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As I know Visual Studio 2015 and above versions has hidden RDLC report viewer. To enable this feature you can go to ControlPanel > Visual Studio 2017 > Right click and choose Update, then you can find the extension for RDLC.

I also found a link to do it easier : [install RDLC extension for report viewer in VisualStudio 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruEIGAmXlZk)

Comment: I have tried this but the ReportViewer control still shows as a non-visual component below the form

Comment: It's weird. I have been the situation like you and I fixed it by doing the same steps in the link I attached above. I hope this link can help you: 
[link link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=125&v=bOnCfq04TXQ)

Comment: Please were you using visual studio 2017 community?

Comment: Yes, I used both VS2017 community and VS2017 Professional. I did install RDLC for both versions and they worked well. For your issue I think you can post a question on Microsoft forum for more information.